# Javascript progress starts only when scrolling a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to give porogress bar on top of a page , when scrolling start a specific div the progress bar should start the progress and ends when that div is over

This method is my refrence from [codepen](https://codepen.io/mgrech/pen/RMJgaM) but it has for the whole page.

HTMl:

```
<div class="progress"></div>

<div class="content">Scroll Down</div>
<div class="content">Even Further</div>
<div class="content">You Made It All The Way!</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
var pixels = $(document).scrollTop();
  var pageHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  var progress = 100 * pixels / pageHeight;
  
  $("div.progress").css("width", progress + "%");
})
```

Comment: Please add relevant piece of code to work with

Comment: I don't have any code , I am just asking an Idea

Comment: So you should be trying it first before you ask